# How can I show a "please wait" window while checking for prerequisites in my installer?

Tags: inno-setup

I do a number of checks in the `InitializeSetup` function in my script. These take about 10 seconds to complete, during which time nothing is displayed except for the window button on the taskbar (clicking it yields nothing). I would like to show a simple "Please wait" window instead. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is sample script that shows how you can create a custom dialog.

Basically create a custom form and place the custom control on it. You can use this as starting point to get the dialog appear as you wish.

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName='Test Date Script'
AppVerName='Test Date Script'
DefaultDirName={pf}\test

[Code]

function InitializeSetup() : boolean;
var
  DlgWait : TSetupForm;
  lblWait : TLabel;
  I : Integer;
begin
  dlgWait :=  CreateCustomForm;
  dlgWait.FormStyle := bsDialog;
  dlgWait.Position := poMainFormCenter;
  lblWait := TLabel.Create(dlgWait);
  lblWait.Parent := dlgWait;
  lblWait.Caption := 'Please Wait';
  lblWait.Visible := True;
  dlgWait.Show;
  dlgWait.Refresh; // Process the paint message

  for I := 0 to 10 do
  begin
     Sleep(1000); // Simulate Functions taking 10 sec
     dlgWait.Refresh;
  end;

  DlgWait.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the window in its own thread? It doesn't help much if you refresh after every iteration since it will be frozen most of the time.