# How can I increase the width of a msgbox() in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, msgbox

Or should have to create my own message box? If so any sample code please

Ok, so it is not possible. I will have to do my own msgbox function.
Should I use a TForm, Tmemo or Tpannel?
How can I have the box hight auto adjustable?
If any one has some sample code I could just start with, I would appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?  How are you getting the `msgbox()`?

Comment: @Teepeemm, that's a pointless question if you know Inno Setup; `MsgBox` is a built-in function that displays a built-in message dialog which does not allow you to modify its size. Your close vote is not fair here, if that was yours; the question is clear (well, it asks just for code, but it's clear what is asked).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increase width of message box in Inno Setup.

You have to implement your own dialog.

Start with creating `TForm` (preferably using [`CreateCustomForm` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustomform)), add `TLabel` to it along with few `TButton`'s. Size all elements properly. At the end call `TForm.ShowModal`.

*The code required is far too long to be asked for here. If you have specific problems, when implementing it, ask separate questions.*

See few examples of building a custom form:

- [Custom Uninstall page (not MsgBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7415457/850848#26588006)
- [How can I show a "please wait" window while checking for prerequisites in my installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6062793/850848)
- [Displaying text from a file in an Inno installer with new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18743519/850848)